# phpunit mock - will return object

Tags: phpunit

Using phpunit mock object, I have a method that returns an object.

How do you code this using the expects / method / will methods?

i.e.

```
 ->will($this->returnValue('Class_Name'));
```

Comment: Everything you need is here: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/test-doubles.html. (in your example the mock will return just a string, you need pass an object to "returnValue" if you want it'll be returned)

Comment: this URL may be more reliable https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 11):

Create the object, and return it with the `returnValue()` function. For example:

```
$myObject = new RandomObject();
$myFactory = $this->getMock('ObjectFactory', array('getRandomObject'));
$myFactory->expects($this->any())->method('getRandomObject')->will($this->returnValue($myObject);

$this->assertInstanceOf('RandomObject', $myFactory->getRandomObject());
```

This will pass.

You can also create that object as a mock itself and pass the mock.